# Turn off logging for a single SL4J Logger instance

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have the following:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
```

and I have used `LOGGER` to write log statements in various places. 
Now I want to disable ALL logging only for `LOGGER` because I want to examine other output. Ideally I want to just write a single statement say `LOGGER.disableAll()` to do so. Is this possible with SL4J?

I am aware I that I can filter the output, but I would like to know if such a method exists as well.

log4j.properties :

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
    log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: This is precisely what your log configuration is for. What backend are you using—Logback? Something else?

Comment: I am using Log4J

Comment: Please show the imports on your `Foo` class.

Comment: Done. So do I have to set a property for class `Foo` in the log configuration file?

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll do, generally, although I will note that if you're using slf4j, Logback is _generally_ a better logger backend (both it and log4j2 were written as more modern replacements for log4j).

Comment: Okay, could you tell me what that statement would look like? I could only find configurations to disable logging entirely but not for a specific class.

Comment: Show your existing configuration.

Comment: I have added the configuration.